# React Native Day view calendar to display event in Android

Tags: react-native

Currently, I am working on React Native Android application to display calendar events in month and day view. I have implemented month view by using the following library.
https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-calendar

I haven't found any library to display events in day view. If anyone knows the library to implement day view calendar events, please provide the links.

Answer (score 0):

## [react-native-sliding-calendar-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sliding-calendar-view)

Example : [demo1](https://github.com/Belobobr/react-native-drop-down-calendar-view/tree/master/examples/SlidingCalendarViewExample)

## [CalendarPicker](https://github.com/stephy/CalendarPicker)

[image]

## [react-native-calendar-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-component)

[image]

## [react-native-calendar-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-datepicker)

[image]

## [react-native-calendar-strip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-strip)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already saw these examples. I want Day View of calender with events displayed on it like google calendar day view.

Comment: I havent tried this. It may this that you are looking for https://github.com/kriskelly/react-native-day-planner

Comment: I tried with above library but unfortunately, I am getting 'react-native-day-planner' is not in the npm registry.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: I know it's been a while, but did you ever find a solution? I found https://github.com/joshyhargreaves/react-native-event-calendar but the documentation/API is not done.